# Server AppFabric Caching - What happens when the memory runs out

Tags: windows-server-2008, windows-server-2008-r2, cache, appfabric

On my Windows Server 2008 R2 machine, I configured to use [Server AppFabric](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff384253.aspx) Caching features.

It has a nice API which I can implement as default caching provider on my [ASP.NET MVC applications.](http://www.devtrends.co.uk/blog/asp.net-mvc-output-caching-with-windows-appfabric-cache)

One question I have in my mind is this: **What happens when the memory runs out?**

In that machine I have 4GB memory. I looked around but couldn't find anything which enables me to configure max. memory usage for AppFabric.

Any idea how should I act in this situation?

Answer (score 2):

You can configure the total memory to be used for AppFabric caching on each cache host in a cluster using the [Set-CacheHostConfig](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff428169%28v=ws.10%29.aspx) Powershell cmdlet. Use the CacheSize parameter (quoted in MB) e.g.

```
Set-CacheHostConfig -HostName MyCacheServer -CachePort 22233 -CacheSize 1024
```

Each cache host also has two memory thresholds, the low and high water marks, expressed as a percentage. I can't find it explicitly written down anywhere on MSDN, but I *assume* these are percentages of the cache size, rather than the percentage of total memory on the machine. Again, you can tune these settings with `Set-CacheHostConfig`.

As stated in [Expiration and Eviction](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee790981.aspx), once the low water mark is reached, expired objects are evicted from the cache (which to me raises the question of *why* they aren't evicted once they expire but that's for another day) on a Least-Recently-Used basis. If the high water mark is reached, unexpired items will be evicted until the low water mark is reached.